# Display NumPy array as continuously updating image with Glumpy

Tags: python, opengl, numpy, plot, glumpy

I've got a simulation model running in Python using NumPy and SciPy and it produces a 2D NumPy array as the output each iteration. I've been displaying this output as an image using matplotlib and the imshow function. However, I've found out about Glumpy, and on its documentation page it says:

*Thanks to the IPython shell, glumpy can be ran in interactive mode where you can experience live update in displayed arrays when their contents is changed.*

However, I can't seem to work out how to do this with the examples they've given. Basically my model runs as a single function which has a big for loop in it to loop for the number of iterations I'm running. At the end of each iteration of the for loop I want to display the array. At the moment I'm using matplotlib to save the image out to a png file, as displaying it on the screen through matplotlib seems to freeze the python process.

I'm sure there's a way to do this with Glumpy, I'm just not sure how, and I can't find any useful tutorials.

Comment: The issue you have with matplotlib freezing the script is fairly common and usually only requires a simple fix, such as using *draw* instead of *plot*, or running ipython in the *-pylab* mode, etc.

Comment: can you post the code that you are using to display the array?  also, what is your `matplotlib.__version__`, because they have changed the way the GUI loop is handled in some significant ways recently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Glumpy documentation is fairly nonexistent! Here's an example of a simple simulation, comparing array visualisation with `glumpy` against `matplotlib`:

```
import numpy as np
import glumpy
from OpenGL import GLUT as glut
from time import time
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots,close
from matplotlib import cm

def randomwalk(dims=(256,256),n=3,sigma=10,alpha=0.95,seed=1):
    """ A simple random walk with memory """
    M = np.zeros(dims,dtype=np.float32)
    r,c = dims
    gen = np.random.RandomState(seed)
    pos = gen.rand(2,n)*((r,),(c,))
    old_delta = gen.randn(2,n)*sigma
    while 1:
        delta = (1.-alpha)*gen.randn(2,n)*sigma + alpha*old_delta
        pos += delta
        for ri,ci in pos.T:
            if not (0. <= ri < r) : ri = abs(ri % r)
            if not (0. <= ci < c) : ci = abs(ci % c)
            M[ri,ci] += 1
        old_delta = delta
        yield M

def mplrun(niter=1000):
    """ Visualise the simulation using matplotlib, using blit for 
    improved speed"""
    fig,ax = subplots(1,1)
    rw = randomwalk()
    im = ax.imshow(rw.next(),interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.hot,animated=True)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox) # cache the background

    tic = time()
    for ii in xrange(niter):
        im.set_data(rw.next())          # update the image data
        fig.canvas.restore_region(background)   # restore background
        ax.draw_artist(im)          # redraw the image
        fig.canvas.blit(ax.bbox)        # redraw the axes rectangle

    close(fig)
    print "Matplotlib average FPS: %.2f" %(niter/(time()-tic))

def gprun(niter=1000):
    """ Visualise the same simulation using Glumpy """
    rw = randomwalk()
    M = rw.next()

    # create a glumpy figure
    fig = glumpy.figure((512,512))

    # the Image.data attribute is a referenced copy of M - when M
    # changes, the image data also gets updated
    im = glumpy.image.Image(M,colormap=glumpy.colormap.Hot)

    @fig.event
    def on_draw():
        """ called in the simulation loop, and also when the
        figure is resized """
        fig.clear()
        im.update()
        im.draw( x=0, y=0, z=0, width=fig.width, height=fig.height )

    tic = time()
    for ii in xrange(niter):
        M = rw.next()           # update the array          
        glut.glutMainLoopEvent()    # dispatch queued window events
        on_draw()           # update the image in the back buffer
        glut.glutSwapBuffers()      # swap the buffers so image is displayed

    fig.window.hide()
    print "Glumpy average FPS: %.2f" %(niter/(time()-tic))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mplrun()
    gprun()
```

Using `matplotlib` with `GTKAgg` as my backend and  using `blit` to avoid drawing the background each time, I can hit about 95 FPS. With `Glumpy` I get about 250-300 FPS, even though I currently a fairly crappy graphics setup on my laptop. Having said that, `Glumpy` is a bit more fiddly to get working, and unless you are dealing with huge matrices, or you need a very high framerate for whatever reason, I would stick with using `matplotlib` with `blit`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [pyformulas 0.2.8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyformulas/) you can use pf.screen to create a non-blocking screen:

```
import pyformulas as pf
import numpy as np

canvas = np.floor(np.random.normal(scale=50, size=(480,640,3)) % 256).astype(np.uint8)
screen = pf.screen(canvas)

while screen.exists():
    canvas = np.floor(np.random.normal(scale=50, size=(480,640,3)) % 256).astype(np.uint8)
    screen.update(canvas)

#screen.close()
```

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer for pyformulas